# Custom validation in yii2

Tags: validation, yii2

I have custom validation in my model

```
        [['abc1','abc2','abc3','abc4', 'skipOnEmpty' => false,], 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
            if ($model->xyz == 1){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        },
            'skipOnEmpty' => false,
        ],
```

where $model->xyz is a dropdownlist.
This validation is working fine but due to this validation forms are not working well, specially where I use session.
Please tell me any other way to do this kind of validations

Comment: can you explain a bit more what exactly the problem is?

Comment: You have an error in your code - the 'skipOnEmpty' you have 2 times.. the first time it should not be there. Otherwise maybe your problem is, that this validation will only work on submitting the code and on the client it will not validate

Comment: Skip on value is not a problem. Actually problem is , this validation is working fine, but due to this validation code, session variables that are used in that form for the next form , doesn't working. session becomes null @Asped

Comment: what i;m doing here is take all form values from post and set in session,and move to next action where i need these values. when i go to next action ,session shows null values due to this code. If i remove this validation, everything is working fine

Comment: Show us how to save the session.

Comment: $session = Yii::$app->session;

$session->set('abcd', $model);
            $session->set('xyz', $modelAddresses);

and then in next action,
$model = $session['abcd']; @XiaosongGuo

Comment: Let's make clear one more thing. It's the session doesn't work, or the value doesn't work. Before you set the model to session, try  print_r($model->getAttributes()), see if the attributes was loaded correctly. I suggest you don't set the whole active record model into session, just set the value of the attributes, then load it at next action.

Comment: I also strongly recommend you to not save the whole ActiveRecord, as it can have various dynamic objects inside and this cannot be saved corectly into the session. I ran into similar problems. So try just to saved `$model->attributes` into session.

Comment: another thing may be, that you have `ajaxValidation` enabled, and maybe it calls your action on the background, just to validate, BUT it runs the whole code, so also saving something into the session. Couldn't you pass the whole controller action and/or view maybe? so we see how your processing is

Comment: @Asped there are a lot of attributes from 2 or three different models, so i can't them put one by one into session. that is why i put whole model into session. this is for the reason of showing information on confirm page before submitting form.

Comment: Look, saving the whole model into session is BAD, as it will not work as expected. If you want to save you trouble, you have to find another solution. Save only the things you need. e.g. only the IDs for the models, and then load them again from the database.. Or just save the data  you want to display in the confirmation.